# Is Sencha Touch 1.1+ supported by Windows 7 Mobile devices?

Tags: windows-phone-7, frameworks, windows-mobile, sencha-touch

Is Sencha Touch 1.1 framework supported by Windows 7 Mobile. I guess it all depends on what kind of webkit support the build in browser on a Windows 7 Mobile devices has.

Any insight, anybody ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not officially supported by Sencha - iOS, Andriod and Blackberry are what Sencha Touch currently supports.

You can see the full list here: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: It's not even unofficially supported :-) We want to support Windows phone in the Touch 2.x product line, but not yet!

Comment: Also check this. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?112315-Sencha-Touch-Support-for-Windows-Phone-7